# Pressing back button on a ModalNavigationDrawer navigates back instead of closing the drawer

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose, and [Compose Destinations](https://composedestinations.rafaelcosta.xyz/) for navigation. My app has a `ModalNavigationDrawer`. The modal opens and closes fine using *gestures*, but when the modal is open I'd like it to be able to close using the back button. This feels like a natural action, and works in just about any other app I've used.

Instead, the back button just closes (minimises) the app, or navigates to the previous screen. I assume this is because Compose Destinations is catching the back action and popping off the back stack. However, the documentation doesn't mention anything about solving this issue at first glance. The only time drawers are mentioned are [here](https://composedestinations.rafaelcosta.xyz/navigation/basics?_highlight=drawer), but this isn't relevant to the issue at hand.

I've found a few posts on SO about how to intercept the back press, but these seem a bit hacky to me. This seems like a basic use case that should have an easy and decent solution. Hence, I came to ask if there is a recommended way of solving this.

The main app looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val navEngine = rememberNavHostEngine()
    val navController = navEngine.rememberNavController()
    val startRoute = HomeRouteDestination

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        DestinationsNavHost(
            engine = navEngine,
            navController = navController,
            navGraph = NavGraphs.root,
            startRoute = startRoute
        )
    }
}
```

My drawer component:

```
private data class DrawerItem(
    val icon: ImageVector,
    val name: String,
    val destination: DirectionDestination
)

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun NavDrawerWrapper(
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator = EmptyDestinationsNavigator,
    content: @Composable (() -> Unit, () -> Unit) -> Unit
) {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val openDrawer: () -> Unit = { scope.launch { drawerState.open() } }
    val closeDrawer: () -> Unit = { scope.launch { drawerState.close() } }

    val items = listOf(
        DrawerItem(Icons.Default.List, "Menu", HomeRouteDestination),
        DrawerItem(Icons.Default.Settings, "Settings", SettingsRouteDestination)
    )

    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(items[0]) }

    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            DrawerSheet(
                items, selectedItem,
                onSelectItem = { item ->
                    closeDrawer()
                    selectedItem = item
                    navigator.navigate(item.destination)
                }
            )
        },
        content = { content(openDrawer, closeDrawer) }
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun DrawerSheet(
    items: List<DrawerItem> = listOf(),
    selectedItem: DrawerItem? = null,
    onSelectItem: (DrawerItem) -> Unit = {}
) {
    ModalDrawerSheet {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 15.dp, vertical = 20.dp)) {
            items(items.size) { index ->
                val item = items[index]
                NavigationDrawerItem(
                    label = { Text(text = item.name) },
                    icon = { Icon(imageVector = item.icon, contentDescription = item.name) },
                    selected = item == selectedItem,
                    onClick = { onSelectItem(item) }
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shorter version of the solution is to use `BackHandler` if you need more customization per screen level.

```
BackHandler(
    enabled = drawerState.isOpen,
) {
    closeDrawer()
}
```

---

I have some util methods and reusable Composable to handle this which I use in my project. I am sharing the same here for reference. Change it according to your requirement.

It is quite large as I use it for my whole app. I have a single Scaffold and this composable works for me.

[GitHub link for exploration](https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/finance-manager/blob/main/codebase/android/core/ui/src/main/java/com/makeappssimple/abhimanyu/financemanager/android/core/ui/common/BottomSheetUtil.kt)

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetHandler(
    showModalBottomSheet: Boolean,
    bottomSheetType: BottomSheetType,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    keyboardController: SoftwareKeyboardController?,
    resetBottomSheetType: () -> Unit,
) {
    BottomSheetDisposeHandler(
        modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        resetBottomSheetType = resetBottomSheetType,
    )

    BottomSheetTypeChangeHandler(
        showModalBottomSheet = showModalBottomSheet,
        bottomSheetType = bottomSheetType,
        coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
        modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        keyboardController = keyboardController,
    )
}

@Composable
private fun BottomSheetDisposeHandler(
    modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    resetBottomSheetType: () -> Unit,
) {
    if (modalBottomSheetState.currentValue != ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
        DisposableEffect(
            key1 = Unit,
        ) {
            onDispose {
                resetBottomSheetType()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun BottomSheetTypeChangeHandler(
    showModalBottomSheet: Boolean,
    bottomSheetType: BottomSheetType,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    keyboardController: SoftwareKeyboardController?,
) {
    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = bottomSheetType,
    ) {
        if (showModalBottomSheet) {
            keyboardController?.hide()
            showModalBottomSheet(
                coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
                modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
            )
        } else {
            hideModalBottomSheet(
                coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
                modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
internal fun BottomSheetBackHandler(
    enabled: Boolean,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    resetBottomSheetType: () -> Unit,
) {
    BackHandler(
        enabled = enabled,
    ) {
        hideModalBottomSheet(
            coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
            modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        ) {
            resetBottomSheetType()
        }
    }
}

private fun showModalBottomSheet(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    action: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        if (modalBottomSheetState.currentValue == modalBottomSheetState.targetValue) {
            modalBottomSheetState.show()
            action?.invoke()
        }
    }
}

private fun hideModalBottomSheet(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    action: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        if (modalBottomSheetState.currentValue == modalBottomSheetState.targetValue) {
            modalBottomSheetState.hide()
            action?.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
BottomSheetBackHandler(
    enabled = = bottomSheetType != HomeBottomSheetType.NONE,
    coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
    modalBottomSheetState = sheetState,
    resetBottomSheetType = onBackPress,
)
```

I use an enum to store the current bottom sheet type.

Comment: So the `BackHandler` was really the way to go here, thanks. In case other people need it, the fix is just one line: `BackHandler(enabled = drawerState.isOpen, onBack = closeDrawer)`. I appreciate the extra context around it but it make the answer look a bit more daunting than it actually is :p